How to iterate over all devices in the Generic Kernel Image?
Demo code:
spin_lock(&devices_kset->list_lock);

while (!list_empty(&devices_kset->list)) {

      dev = list_entry(devices_kset->list.prev, struct device, kobj.entry);

When I use the above code to traverse the kernel device. The compilation will give an error like below.
error: use of undeclared identifier 'devices_kset'

Because it's a GKI. devices_ksetsymbols not exported.
Is there any other way to Iterate over all kernel devices on GKI？

Each device is attached to a bus, you can't iterate over all devices in one go. You need to list the busses you want to iterated devices over. Easiest way is to do that in the user space.
